# I want to take runtime input instead of commandline argument, How to do it?

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  //################################
  // Variables
  //################################

  // common
  int num_of_params; // number of command-line parameters

  // related to files
  //string data_filename;
  char data_filename[CHUNK_BUF_SIZE];              // input file path

  int data_filesize = 0;        // data file size

  // related to chunks
  int fd;                       // file descriptor to check boundary
  int size;                     // size of input data
  unsigned char *buf;           // input data

  int offset      = 0;        // file offset
  int chunk_b_pos = 0 ;       // beginning position of a chunk in a file
  int chunk_e_pos = -1;       // ending position of a chunk in a file
                                // *** NOT 0 ** due to "set_breakpoint() in chunk_sub.c"
                                //
  int cur_chunk_size = 0;       // !!!! Accumulated chunk size !!!!
                                // This value is compared to minimum chunk size and maximum chunk size

  int chunk_index_fd;           // file which contains chunk indexes for a document
  char chunk_index_filepath[CHUNK_BUF_SIZE];     // chunk index file path


  // parameters
  int avg_chunk_size;           // expected averge chunk size
  int min_chunk_size;           // minimum chunk size
  int max_chunk_size;           // maximum chunk size

  // temporary command
  char cmd[CHUNK_BUF_SIZE];

  int num_of_breakpoints = 0;


  //################################
  // Check parameters
  //################################
  // get number of command-line parameters
  num_of_params = argc - 1;

  if (num_of_params != 4)
  {
    printf("usage : %s <input file> <expected avg chunk size> <min chuk size> <max chunk size>\n",
            argv[0]);
    printf("e.g.    %s body 8192 2048 65535\n", argv[0]);
    printf("***     try to change 1024 to 2048, 4096, and 8192, and see results\n");
    exit(1);
  }


  strcpy(data_filename, argv[1]); // input data filename
  avg_chunk_size = atoi(argv[2]);
  min_chunk_size = atoi(argv[3]);
  max_chunk_size = atoi(argv[4]);
```

this program takes commandline argument,

eg. >chunk body 8192 2048 65535

where body is filename and others are chunk parameters

my question is i dont want commandline parameters, i want to take input while running the program. how to do it.

Comment: Your first step is to figure out which language you want to use: C or C++.

Comment: c++ language...

Comment: Then you can start by actually writing C++ code. That means using `std::string`, instead of error-prone `char` arrays, and emitting output to `std::cout`, instead of using C library `printf()`. And to read input interactively, use `operator>>` with `std::cin`, and you will find plenty of examples for doing that in your C++ book.

Comment: i tried in c++, but not working. Can u tell, how to do it in C language.

Comment: By the way, if *u* can type *parameters*, then u can type **you** properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to take runtime input using C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(void)
{
  std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
  int number;
  std::cin >> number;
  std::cout << "\nYour number is: " << number << "\n";

  std::cout << "\n\nPaused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n'); // Wait for Enter to be pressed.
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The "`std::cin >> number`" is how to input from standard input using C++.

To read from a file, use `std::ifstream` to create the file.  For more examples, search the internet for "c++ ifstream open file".

Comment: Let's not encourage the bad habit of using `operator>>` with line-oriented interactive input processing. A good chunk of questions here are from lost souls who are led astray in that direction, and end up with `fail()`ed `std::cin`, or a mixture of `>>` and `getline` resulting in a major clusterfracas. Always use `getline()` with line-oriented input, consistently.